# .net application to paste data on word document

Tags: .net

I have created windows application in c#.net from where user will be able to add text and save in database. Now I want functionality like that user will be able to drag the displayed text on the screen(Already saved in database) to word application and the text will paste on the ms-word document.

If some one has idea to do this then please give me suggestion to do the same.

Thanks,

Munish

Comment: you can export the text to word, dragging seems little weird user opening a blank word document and drag the test is that really you want??

Comment: Yes I want that if user will drag text from my .net application to ms-word then it will paste there.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do it with Drag&Drop I think you should handle the Drag&Drop events, like BeginDrag, DragEnter and Drop... in case the .NET events are not enough there are also certain Windows APIs designed for that. I have seen an example long time ago of an application which was creating a file on the desktop if there was some content dropped in there from the application.